# Crosstab Query in R

Tags: r, crosstab

How would someone change this data from:

```
FY      FedNonFed   TotalExpense
2006    Federal     46753094
2007    Federal     43397314
2008    Federal     43962330
2006    Non Federal 74740716
2007    Non Federal 74834857
2008    Non Federal 71051132
```

to

```
FY      Federal     Non Federal
2006    46753094    74740716
2007    43397314    74834857
2008    43962330    71051132
```

My attempts with xtabs(), table() haven't been that successful. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `dcast(df, FY ~ FedNonFed)`. you need to load `library(reshape2)` first

Comment: `xtabs(TotalExpense ~ FY + FedNonFed, data=dat)` does it, as would `reshape(dat, idvar="FY", direction="wide", timevar="FedNonFed")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also use `tidyr::spread`. Assuming data frame is named `dataset`:

```
library(tidyr)
dataset %>% spread(FedNonFed, TotalExpense)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(reshape)
cast(FedNonFed, FY ~ FedNonFed)
```

About as simple as that :-)